# overlay image/icon on background image in android

Tags: android

I am using an image as my application background. What I am trying to do is to put a small cross(like an image or icon) at where my finger touched. Does anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to listen to the touch event and for each touch event, you can read its coordinate and display image view. Detail implementation is explained here [Place image at coordinates Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020612/place-image-at-coordinates-android).

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know how that guy got it working. My problem is I can't see the image at all.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124278/add-an-image-view-at-a-new-location-on-screen