# Put a custom pin over an image and get its coordinates

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView with an image loaded,

I want that when the user clicks in a point of the image, another little image(used as pin) is overlapped in this point and the coordinates of the point are returned.

But I haven't idea of how could I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place a image at a certain coordinates you will have to draw the image on the canvas .
To get the coordinates of the touch event  use the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            mTouchX = event.getX();
            mTouchY = event.getY();//stores touch event
        } else {
            mTouchX = -1;
            mTouchY = -1;
        }
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Here is the code for drawing the image on canvas [Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/android-image-in-canvas-with-touch-events)
hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

It will help you to place image based on the co-ordinates. So it can be overlapped

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020612/place-image-at-coordinates-android)