# How can we place image on given axis on any view or viewgroup

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Hello i am developing an application like lenskart or snapchat and i have successfully detected the eyes and  face in given image and after detection i have the co-ordiantes of the eyes and face of person in image so i just wanted to place image of glasses on the face can anyone help me how can i do this ?

[image: As we can see here the eyes are detected and circle are drawn on eyes]

i have tried [Geeks for geeks how can we place image on axis we touch on screen](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-insert-image-to-screen-at-the-touched-coordinates-in-android/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020612/place-image-at-coordinates-android)

Comment: do you want to place the image of glass automatically or after clicking the co-ordinates?

Comment: @REX As per his question, it has to automatically place the image of glass.

Comment: @REX as seen in image i have detected the eyes and after detection eyes i am having x and y axis of both right and left eye and after that i just wanted to place image of glasses on that x and y axis so that it looks like glasses are placed on face .

Comment: If you have the eyes co-ordinates the you can create a custom view and add glasses on top of your imageview using canvas by using some math to figure out glasses image position.